# Are there any other GIF creation libraries for Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gif

I'd really love to know if there are better GIF file creation libraries for Android development. I've already tried [this one](https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder/blob/master/GifEncoder.java) as well an NDK based one called gifflen (it's really old apparently). Both I've found are slow and produce low colour amount GIFs with incredibly big inflated file sizes with quality settings that don't seem to do anything. Worst comes to worst I could just write the thing myself but it would save a lot of trouble if anyone knows of an existing one, thanks in advance.

Comment: As I am the author of gifflen I guess I can comment on your comments: The quality setting affects the number of pixels sampled by the color quantizer. A lower quality setting means fewer pixels sampled, which leads to slightly worse results but faster processing. You're right that it only supports up to 256 colors per frame (typical for GIF, although the format does allow for TrueColor as well). The output file size will depend on the source content, the number of colors used, the number of frames/second etc. The compression algorithm is fixed and should not differ from other implementations.